# Gitlab Runner 14.4 not picking up jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab:14.4.0
Gitlab-Runner:14.4.0 & 13.0.1

After I upgrade Gitlab from 13.6.3 to 14.4.0, all Runner could not pick up jobs
I thought it was Runner version too old，but Gitlab-Runner:14.4.0 on other Linux vm show the same problem

`gitlab-runner status` looks normal

But when I use `gitlab-runner --debug run` on each vm, Runner work for few minutes, the runner on that vm could pick up jobs, now I run this command manual every 5 minute to keep other developer working

---

the problem is we deploy gitlab use docker version image on hand wirte Deployment deploy on Kubernetes, the background jobs fail and stuck many times, after we transfer data to new Gitlb which deploy by helm problem solved

Comment: Can you check which user is used to run or install gitlab-runner ?

Comment: On the GitLab server, can you run `sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:check` to see if there's any errors? Also, in the admin UI, see if your background migrations have completed without errors. Technically, you're [supposed to install either 14.1 or 14.0.5 before installing 14.2+](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#1400) of GitLab. Also check your `production.log` for errors on the GitLab server from the runners. Were any other changes made to your GitLab settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. But I figured it came from the GitLab instance iteself.

The problem was thensolved by upgrading to 14.4.2. I don't think it's the update itself, but the restart of the GitLab instance after the upgrade proved useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into a similar issue (GitLab EE v14.2.3-ee) whereby all 3 runners where in a wait state for minutes at a time, before any pending jobs were eventually picked up.  Resolved the issue by...

- removing all runners,
- resetting the `config.toml` file (which was cluttered with `[[runner]]` entries from former runners),
- restarting GitLab, and
- then creating new runners.

Specifically, I performed the following steps...

1. Delete all runners via "GitLab console > Admin > Overview > Runners".
2. Log into runner host(s), find [config.toml](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html), and clean out the entire file except for...

```
concurrent=5
check_interval=0

[session_server]
   session_timeout = 1800
```

3. Log into GitLab EE host and [restart GitLab EE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/restart_gitlab.html).

```
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

4. Log into the runner host(s), and [create new runners](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/) (follow directions from "GitLab console > Admin > Overview > Runners" )

After the above corrective action, the runners now immediately pick up pending jobs.